# How to get Netbeans to leave array initializer closing brace on new line

Tags: java, netbeans

Netbeans when formatting Java code seems to insist on putting the closing brace of an array initializer on the same line as the last element:

```
String[] names = {
  "a",
  "b",};
```

Is there a way to get it to leave the closing brace on a new line...

```
String[] names = {
  "a",
  "b",
};
```

... without messing up the way it formats code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it keeps the closing brace on the next line if you remove the last comma.